# How to use a GPG key for SSH on macOS

Tags: ssh, macos, gpg, ssh-agent, gpg-agent

Basically, my goal is to use a single key for everything. I have a GPG key that I imported onto my MacBook, and would like to use that key for SSH authentication. However, despite my several attempts, I cannot get my key to list. I have, for the most part, been following the guide here: https://gregrs-uk.github.io/2018-08-06/gpg-key-ssh-mac-debian/ trying minor variations to see if it would have an impact. But when I run `ssh-add -l` I get the customary "The agent has no identities."

I notice the guide is relatively old (written in 2018), so has anyone had success with using a GPG key for SSH on Mac? Is it simply a lost cause? Any help would be much appreciated!

Added `enable-ssh-support` to my gpg-agent.conf file

Added the GPG key keygrip to my sshcontrol file

Added:

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)
gpgconf --launch gpg-agent
```

to my .zprofile (I suspect this is where the issue lies)

And still nothing after running `ssh-add -l`

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a really dumb mistake: I didn't correctly import my key pair into my Mac, since I generated it on a different machine. After re-importing the key shows up.